# Children floating using percentages does not fill container 100% in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, layout, webkit, css-float

I can't figure this one out.

It seems to work in IE8+ and Firefox, but Chrome displays it "wrong" (maybe it's right, who knows):

[image]

I am using Bootstrap, so I am not sure if that's affecting anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/kamranayub/zVbHz/3/

The bars need to be fluid for my purposes, so pixel widths won't work. I am not sure if IE/Firefox are masking an issue and if Chrome is being honest with me.

If you can't figure it out, any alternative ideas for a fluid set of progress bars?

Comment: Worked in Chrome for me on both Windows and Mac OS.

Comment: @kinakuta: Try adjusting the width of your window.

Comment: @thirtydot I did - maybe I don't understand the problem - the behavior was identical on all browsers either way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your problem. I guess it's rounding all the percentages the same way, so you have a noticeable change in total width when you float them next to each other.

In order to keep it to a maximum 1px total error, I'd make sure that all the right edges are defined from the main container and the last one touches the right edge, instead of relying on the browser compensating for rounding error. Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nZYt/1/

```
.progress {
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.progress .bar {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}
.progress .bar:first-child {
    border-right:none;
}

.progress .bar.bar-remaining {
    filter: none;
    background: red;
}
```

and

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar bar-remaining" style="width: 100%"></div>
    <div class="bar bar-remaining" style="width: 75%"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 50%"></div>
    <div class="bar" style="width: 25%"></div>
</div>
```

You could target the individual divs with CSS's [nth-child](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=nth-child) selector instead of hard-coding widths or special classes in your markup.

But it's still a bit ugly in my opinion, and you'll have to play a bit to get your rounded corners looking right again.

What about drawing it on a [HTML5 Canvas](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/) and using this html-based version as a fall-back?

**edit**: I don't know anything about bootstrap, but hopefully this is still applicable!

Comment: Thanks, this will point me in the right direction. I am building the bars via Knockout.js, so I should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is because of the size of your progress bar. Its width is `514px` and you have 5 `div`s with 20% width inside it. So the width of each inner `div`s is `514px/5 = 102.80px` and its simply omitting the fractional value. Try giving the width of your progress bar `515px` and remove the right margin of your red box.

edit 1 : you need to try to keep the width of the progress bar is a multiplication of the number of the `div`s inside.

Answer (score -1):

Set the padding and margins to zero. That should fix the gap you are seeing.